# I am getting the following errors when I upload an image in macOS Catalina

Tags: php

My code worked perfectly when all I was doing was upload files into the database. But when I tried to store it also in folder, I'm getting a
warning:

> move_uploaded_file(files/picture.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied and move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpB59AaC' to 'files/picture.jpg

```
I'm also tried about permissions and echo the path and directory give me currently path
I think I'm missing something important but i cant figure out here is my codes:
  html code->>> 
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
            <input name="myfile" type="file">
            <button>
                go!
            </button>
        
        </form>
phpcode->>>
       <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['myfile'])){
        $file=$_FILES['myfile'];
        $fileName=$file['name'];
        $fileSize=$file['size'];
        $fileTmp=$file['tmp_name'];
        $fileType=$file['type'];
        $fileError=$file['error'];
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $target='files/';
        $newName='picture';
        if ($fileType != 'image/jpg' and $fileType != 'image/jpeg'){
        $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($fileSize > 5242880){
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($uploadOk == 1){
            $ext=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
            $target=$target . $newName . '.' . $ext;
        
        
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $target);
        }
        
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: PHP is mot allowed to access the files drawer. You have to change the access rights to this drawer. Even it is not a good idea to have a writeable drawer inside of your html directory

Comment: how to change the access rights in drawer

Comment: but it's a bad practice , do you suggest an alternative way ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem about permissions.You can try to change the permission about the folder to read&write for everybody.
[try like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoMjv.png)

Comment: I,m also tried about permission .but it still not working

Comment: Default permissions for a macOS sierra user provide read-write access on the home directory. The error above clearly indicates it is trying to move something from /Applications directory (unless your error message is actually the other way around). Can you please check if you can move this file manually first, without getting the 'elevated permissions' dialog box? If you see the UI asking for admin permissions, the process needs permissions allocated on this directory - refer to chmod documentation.

Comment: I gave full Disk access for my Xampp but it still not work can show me the right path if you know